# Phonetic similarity metric for NLP (English)

Tags: natural-language-processing

I am looking for similarity metrics of phonemes (expressed in IPA) in English. In other words, given two phonemes A and B (both written), I want to know how similar they are based on some metric, M. For example, M(ɒ, oʊ) would yield a higher score than M(æ,ɔɪ).

Answer (score 1):

Distance metrics like Leveshtein or Hamming distance working on IPA phoneme symbols are simply comparing arbitrary symbols; and the phoneme /a/ would be as distant from /b/ as the much closer /p/ would be. Also, most of these metrics only work on *sequences* of phonemes, not individual phonemes.

What I would do is to describe each phoneme by a feature vector, including

- place of articulation (labiar, alveolar, etc)
- voiced/unvoiced
- type of articulation (plosive, fricative, etc)

You can then use a distance metric on this feature vector to decide how similar phonemes are. For example:

1. /b/: bilabial, plosive, voiced
2. /s/: dental, fricative, unvoiced
3. /p/: bilabial, plosive, unvoiced

A simple binary measure would easily tell you that /b/ and /p/ are closer to each other than /b/ and /s/. A suitable metric to use would be the [Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient).